# How do I manually find the flash chip and -c parameter? (Flashing Skulls BIOS using Pi 4)

Tags: pi-4, video

Using a Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspberry Pi OS I'm trying to flash Skulls BIOS onto a Lenovo Thinkpad T440p using [this guide](https://github.com/merge/skulls/blob/master/t440p/README.md#first-time-installation).

How do I get the Raspberry Pi to detect my laptop's 8MB BIOS chip? I've made sure to first connect the clip to the 8MB BIOS chip before the Raspberry Pi and ensired that the red wire is in slot 1 of the adapter and on the dot on the BIOS chip. I've completed the other prep work from the guide. The terminal output says:

```
user@Exemplary4145:~ $ ls
'BOINC Manager-user'   Desktop     Downloads   Pictures   Templates
 Bookshelf             Documents   Music       Public     Videos
user@Exemplary4145:~ $ cd skulls/
bash: cd: skulls/: No such file or directory
user@Exemplary4145:~ $ ls
'BOINC Manager-user'   Desktop     Downloads   Pictures   Templates
 Bookshelf             Documents   Music       Public     Videos
user@Exemplary4145:~ $ Downloads
bash: Downloads: command not found
user@Exemplary4145:~ $ cd Downloads
user@Exemplary4145:~/Downloads $ cd skulls-1.0.8
user@Exemplary4145:~/Downloads/skulls-1.0.8 $ sudo ./external_install_bottom.sh -m -k <backup-file-to-create>
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
user@Exemplary4145:~/Downloads/skulls-1.0.8 $ sudo ./external_install_bottom.sh -m -k <8MB backup>
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
user@Exemplary4145:~/Downloads/skulls-1.0.8 $ sudo ./external_install_bottom.sh -m -k 8MB backup
[sudo] password for user: 
Skulls

Please select the hardware you use:
1) Raspberry Pi
2) CH341A
3) Tigard
4) Exit
Please select the hardware flasher: 1
Ok. Run this on a Rasperry Pi.
trying to detect the chip...
chip not detected.
flashrom v1.2 on Linux 6.1.21-v8+ (aarch64)
flashrom is free software, get the source code at 
https://flashrom.org/


Using clock_gettime for delay loops (clk_id: 1, resolution: 1ns).
No EEPROM/flash device found.
Note: flashrom can never write if the flash chip isn't found automatically.
chip not detected. Please find it manually and rerun with the -c parameter.
```

Comment: you should be asking at a site that deals with the Lenovo Thinkpad Skulls BIOS

Comment: @jsotola They only have a [GitHub](https://github.com/merge/skulls/blob/master/t440p/README.md) and I'm not sure how to ask questions on there.

Comment: look at the top of that page